# Having trouble instantiating C++ class from objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I'm mixing C++ with ObjectiveC for a Cocos2d (objective-C) and Box2D (C++) project.

I have the following C++ class:

```
class ActorListener : public b2ContactListener
{ 
    public :
    const b2Body* Owner;

    ActorListener(const b2Body* owner);
    ~ActorListener();

    virtual void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
    virtual void EndContact(b2Contact* contact);
    virtual void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold);    
    virtual void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse);
};
```

Which I try to initialise with:

(in header)

```
ActorListener* Listener;
```

(in mm file)

```
Listener = new ActorListener(Body);
```

I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "vtable for ActorListener", referenced from:
      ActorListener::ActorListener(b2Body const*)in ActorListener.o
      ActorListener::ActorListener(b2Body const*)in ActorListener.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vtable is emitted in the same file as the first virtual function of the class.  In this case, `~ActorListener()` is the first virtual method, because `b2ContactListener::~b2ContactListener()` is virtual.  Did you remember to define `ActorListener::~ActorListener()` somewhere?

Comment: Thanks. There is a very descriptive message when you forget a regular virtual (like the ones I had lower) but that very general one if you forgot destructor.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get XCode to use g++ to do the linking. You can force this either by including a C++ source file on the link line -- even a fake, essentially empty one -- or (I think) by explicitly linking with /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib .

Comment: Can you explain how to do this in more detail? (noob at xcode)

Comment: Literally just including a source file named `fake.cpp` in your project containing `#define FOO 1` will do it.